# IOS: Tabbar Item -> Navigation Controller View -> Table View Item -> Detail View

Tags: ios4

Could someone help me, i'm looking for help for next question: i wanna change navigation controller's current view to table row item's detail view; my navigation contoller is located as tabbar's item, table and other buttons are located as a objects in navigation controller current view.

thanks in advance!